# resetting defaults for xcode projects in iphone development

Tags: iphone, xcode, templates

I was trying to add cocos template for game development.

I was trying some R & D.

R & D was " How to add template of COCOS in x code ? "

But By mistake I made Some horrible changes to " My Seniors Sir's Mac ".

How to reset?

I have replace all the previous templates.

Now I don't know How to reset it.

When I click on File menu.

Choose new project

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering we don't know exactly what you changed, is reinstalling Xcode an option?

Comment: I have replace iphone projects templates with mac os x projects templates. If your x code is working correctly. Just do one thing for me. Compress & send me iphone project templates.

Comment: It's probably a lot easier for you to just re-download the iPhone SDK and reinstall it.  You could also install it on a different machine and just copy over the templates yourself.